# Loader interceptor hides the loader before getting response in angular

Tags: angular

I am showing a loading bar using HTTP interceptor in my angular project that shows loader whenever an HTTP request is sent to the serve.

**loader.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {

  isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor() { }

  show() {

    this.isLoading.next(true);
  }

  hide() {

    this.isLoading.next(false);
  }

}
```

**loader-interceptor.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { LoaderService } from '../services/loader.service';

@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    this.loaderService.show();
    return next.handle(request).pipe( finalize( () => this.loaderService.hide()) );
  }

}
```

Problem is that loader hides before the data has been loaded. This happens especially if there is a lot of data. I want the loader not to hide unless all the requests have been resolved so that's user is not able to interact with forms etc. unless the data is loaded. The loader HTML uses overlay CSS to block users to interact with forms until data has arrived.

In another project, I used to do call these hide/show methods in service calls when I was subscribing to the service methods in every component. I want to avoid this because this requires me to add this code again and again in every component.

Any solution for this problem ?

**PS:**
Is it problematic to handle loader when there are multiple HTTP requests in different components simultaneously ?

Comment: Strange, this should work. Can you maybe try with "return next.handle(request).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
        this.loaderService.hide();
      }
    );"

Comment: @riorudo. I will check this. I wish to know to the cause of problem.

Comment: seems like you are hiding the loader in request itself , should have specified to intercept the response

Comment: try https://github.com/kKen94/ngx-progress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be hiding the loader on response:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.show();
    return next.handle(req).pipe(map(event => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
           this.loaderService.hide();
        }         
        return event;
    }));
}
```

Comment: yes. I have tried but this is't working. I am trying to figure out what is the problem with my implementation.

Comment: @Jeol, I have tried to console.log((event instanceof HttpResponse)) and it is always giving false and falls into and endless loop.

Comment: it is fixed. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I also face the same issue due to multiple async API calls.
But I have written different logic. so would like to share here maybe it will help someone.

I am expecting you have created one loader component where you are subscribing isLoading state.

so in that component just create
one variable

```
showLoader: boolean[] = [];
```

and inside of subscriber instead of assigning that true/ false value just do push or pop operation into a boolean array(code is below).

and in your HTML you can show/ hide your loader with checking the length of the array
e.g. **this.showLoader.length**

```
this.LoaderService.isLoading.subscribe((val: boolean) => {
      if (val){
          this.showLoader.push(val);
        } else {
          this.showLoader.pop();
        }
    })
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, It is useful in case if you are calling multiple api simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

**If we are having multiple api calls then please use this one..**

export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

```
showLoaderCustom: any[] = [];
constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
   
    this.loaderService.show();
    this.showLoaderCustom.push(request);
    return next.handle(request).pipe(tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.showLoaderCustom.pop();
            if(this.showLoaderCustom.length == 0){
                this.loaderService.hide();
            }
        }
    },
        (err: any) => {
            this.showLoaderCustom.pop();
            if(this.showLoaderCustom.length == 0){
                this.loaderService.hide();
            }
        }));
}
```

}